# MySQL "No Database Selected" Error ( 1046 ) using xdevapi and node

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am just trying to do a very basic nearly "Hello World" using the @mysql/xdevapi module found on NPM to simply get the rows in a database I've made.

```
const mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');

const config = {
    password: 'agoodpassword!',
    user: 'user',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 33060,
    schema: 'myDatabase'
};

mysqlx
    .getSession(config)
    .then(session => {
    return session
    .sql('SELECT * FROM `myTable`;')
    .execute();
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

I couldn't think of anything more simple than this to just see if I can make the connector work since I was unsuccessful using it as part of my fully project.

I still just get the "No database selected" error when it is clearly listed in my options next to the keyword "Schema"... Schema and Database are the same thing if I recalled correctly...

I really don't know what is wrong, any help would really be appreciated.

I am referencing this for how to work with this module ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/ )

Answer (score 0):

Currently, even though you are able to define a default schema using the connection options (`myDatabase` in your example), that schema does not stick for session-level operations such as executing raw SQL statements with `.sql()`.

You have two options to overcome this limitation. Either you define the schema in the query itself:

```
return session.sql('SELECT * FROM `myDatabase`.`myTable`').execute()
```

Or, you explicitly switch to that specific schema within the session context:

```
return session.sql('USE `myDatabase`')
  .execute()
  .then(() => {
    return session.sql('SELECT * FROM `myTable`')
      .execute()
  })
```

Disclaimer: I'm the xdevapi Node.js connector lead dev.

Comment: This answer is a classical "hack" solution, probably influenced by some forum/online prototyping tool/github issue hack response like this one: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1123 . I must emphasize this: when people reply on github issue, they often offer a "hack" solution or a quick prototype to bypass a blocking issue for others, in order to help or escalate with the developers in order to fix an issue. It should not be accepted answer and it gets downvoted not because respondent downvoted my answer, but to focus all others to utilize regular solutions when such as present.

Comment: Yes, the solution is a hack. But that's due to the limited feature support in he API for that Schema thing. We noticed that setting the default schema for SQL was confusing with the document/CRUD `getSchema()` method and expressions in there where it wasn't clear which  schema was used in expressions. Thus even so the Userguide unfortunately mentiones it this was -- for the moment -- removed from the API and only he way using `use` or by fully qualifying names works. And Rui quite well knows this stuff, since he actually implemented large parts of it (the parts which I didn't implement)

Comment: I would not call it a hack, but I agree it's probably not pretty (but that's mostly opinion). In any case, there's a reason behind it, as Johannes mentioned, but we also appreciate the feedback, and, just like every piece of software out there, there's a chance this might change in the future. All and all, the fact is that this is, currently and unfortunately (or not), the only solution.

Comment: OK, then I am reversing the downvote if this is currently the only way (cannot reverse the downvote for now). I am generally using java, not javascript. However, I do use angular 5/6 for front-end in my recent projects and am familiar with the yarn/npm packaging... and I immediately checked about npm/github docs as well, https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-nodejs . Does getSchema() work properly, as intended, when setting/choosing the schema via nodejs ? It's definitely misleading if neither of these options work for nodejs, while the javascript code in official docs hints otherwise.

Comment: The wrong docs certainly is an issue and we are truly thankful for that being highlighted, will get this fixed. Also the SQL-side will improve, our primary focus is the "DocStore" JSON/Collection/CRUD stuff ... so many ideas, so little time :-)

Comment: As far as I can tell, `getSchema()` should work as intended, but if you find some issue, feel free to report a bug and we can take a look. Also, the "JavaScript" code in the official docs usually refers to the Shell, not the connector, which usually has examples under "Node.js".

Comment: sadly, I can't reverse the downvote to upvote unless your answer is edited. The mods should also edit the answer and proclaim it as correct. An update disclaimer by you or the mods would be great to point on the issue for those who stumble upon it by googling.

Comment: No problem. Hopefully people will check the comments as well. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Please re-think on your next step before applying any of the "hack" solutions like writing the schema name in your every table/column select. Check upon the official documentation, your issue is described in [**HERE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/setting-the-current-schema.html).

I will post the opening words and you can see they directly addressed your issue in the docs:

> A newly opened session has no schema set. There is no concept of an implicitly set default schema when a session is established. A default schema can be defined, but a session's current schema is not set to a default before being explicitly selected.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. Once again, even though you are able to set a default schema, it won't stick to session-level operations which is what the OP wants to perform in this case.

Comment: Then I need to point you towards the official documentation as well, since it seems you didn't care to read. Quoting it: "Upon creation, the Session class has no schema selected by default. Therefore, the runSql() function does not know which schema to execute the SQL statement against. Use the Session class setCurrentSchema() function to set or change the current schema."

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation is not correct. The behavior is not consistent for all connectors depicted there. I know this because I'm the maintainer of the Node.js connector :).

Comment: That's interesting, because setCurrentSchema() is intended to work as an official "work-around". Can you verify it by an online example to check on what environment causes it for you?

Comment: If you look closely, you will see there is no Node.js snippet in the docs. `setCurrentSchema()` or some alternative like `setDefaultSchema()` don't exist, as of today, in the Node.js connector. So, the docs are not actually incorrect, but I would say they are misleading.